# Laravel Passport API: createToken get id

Tags: php, laravel, api, token, laravel-passport

## Situation

I'm using Laravel Passport API to communicate between Laravel and external "agents" via Personal Access Tokens: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/passport#personal-access-tokens

You can create tokens: via `$token = \Auth::user()->createToken('name')->accessToken;`

($token then holds only the token itself, not the object)

## Question

How can I get the `token()->id` for a newly created token?

## Background

I need to get the ID to store it in the database to make relation to other table.

Comment: The token is stored in the database, in the table `oauth_access_tokens`. There the token gets an ID.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should split the token creation:

First create the object, this returns a Laravel\Passport\PersonalAccessTokenResult Object:

`$tokenobj = \Auth::user()->createToken('name');`

Then you can get the accessToken itself via:

`$token = $tokenobj->accessToken;`

And the token id via:

`$token_id = $tokenobj->token->id;`

Comment: What is the name parameter for?

Comment: It's just a descriptive name for the token you are creating.